# vue-native - Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined

Tags: react-native, vue.js, native, expo, vue-native

I'm trying to setup vue-native in my pc.
but i get this error [click on the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzupE.png)

I'm using  https://vue-native.io/ as a reference

this is my package .json

```
          {
            "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
            "scripts": {
              "start": "expo start",
              "android": "expo start --android",
              "ios": "expo start --ios",
              "web": "expo start --web",
              "eject": "expo eject"
            },
            "dependencies": {
              "expo": "^35.0.0",
              "react": "16.8.3",
              "react-dom": "16.8.3",
              "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
              "react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
            },
            "devDependencies": {
              "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
            },
            "private": true
          }
```